# Jenkins email routing based on failure reason

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

**The Problem:**

I am interested in being able to select the recipients of a build failure email based on the reason for failure - essentially we have test failures where each error message will have an associated team that is responsible for fixing it. As opposed to routing the email to a fixed distribution list and then manually pass on to the relevant team, I am keen to automate this (to a point!)...

**The Background:**

We have installed the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and I am already using the Groovy pre-send script to alter recipients based on one type of error but we have a huge list that we'd like to do this for.

**One Possible Solution:**

My proposed solution right now is to add some code to the build process that listens to these errors, queries an error messages csv file for the relevant team, maps that against a support distribution rota file for all teams and then logs the suggested distribution list for the email. The groovy script could then simply pull the list out of the logs and set the recipients.

I like this solution because we can then have external control of our error mappings and distribution lists for teams, plus the code around it can be sourced controlled...

...but is there a better way?

Comment: Nope, you've got it right

Comment: I agree with @Slav. This is a good solution for your needs.